# how to load items in QListWidget with scroll

Tags: linux, qt, icons, qlistwidget

I am adding icons to a listwidget. It is working good for say a 200 or 300 icons but i may have to add 1000 or above. So i need to add or load the icons in listwidget only when i scroll down. Now i have used a for loop but i need to avoid this

```
imagefiles = imagedir.entryList(QStringList() << "*.jpg",QDir::Files);
if(imagefiles.isEmpty())
{
    empty->raise();
    empty->show();
}
else
{
    imagelist->repaint();

    for(const QString& f:imagefiles)
    {
        final_row++;
        const QString finalimage=imagepath+QString::fromStdString("/") +f;
        QFileInfo fi(finalimage);
        imagelist->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(QIcon(fi.absoluteFilePath()),fi.fileName()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this ? When loading all the icons is it very slow ?

Comment: Yes it is very slow. I need it for a project where i am required to show the images in a particular path